# Display confirmation box before edit

Tags: jquery, ajax

I use ajax to edit directly data in table. I would like to display a confirm box before editing. The user has only to click on a field and  then he can edit. If he let blank an alert pops up. Now i would like to display a confirm box after edit is done. This is where i'm stuck. behold my codes.

```
<tr>
<th cursor:pointer">NomFaculte</th>
 <th cursor:pointer">Adresse</th>
</tr>
<?php
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($resa))
{
?>
<tr class="edit_tr">
<td class="edit_td" id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
<span id="Adresse_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="text"><?php echo   
$row['Adresse']; ?></span>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['Adresse']; ?>" class="editbox"
id="Adresse_input_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"/>
 </td>
 <td class="edit_td" id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
<span id="NomDroyen_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="text"><?php echo 
 $row['NomDroyen']; ?></span>
 <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['NomDroyen']; ?>" 
  class="editbox" id="NomDroyen_input_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"/>
 </td>


$(document).ready(function()
{

$(".edit_td").click(function()
{
   document.getElementById('user_insert').style.display="none";

 var ID=$(this).attr('id');
$("#Adresse_"+ID).hide();
$("#NomDroyen_"+ID).hide();



$("#Adresse_input_"+ID).show();
 $("#NomDroyen_input_"+ID).show();


}).change(function()
  {

 var ID=$(this).attr('id');
 var Ad=$("#Adresse_input_"+ID).val();
 var NomD=$("#NomDroyen_input_"+ID).val();
 var dataString = 'id='+ ID +'&Adresse='+Ad+'&NomDroyen='+NomD;
if(Ad.length>0&& NomD.length>0)
{

$.ajax({

type: "POST",
url: "faculte_modifier.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
 success: function(html)
 {

$("#Adresse_"+ID).html(Ad);
$("#NomDroyen_"+ID).html(NomD);
$("#NombreEtudiants_"+ID).html(NombEtu);

}
});

}
else
{
alert('Don't let this field empty !.');
}

});

// Edit input box click action
$(".editbox").mouseup(function()
{
return false
});

// Outside click action
$(document).mouseup(function()
{
$(".editbox").hide();
$(".text").show();
  document.getElementById('user_insert').style.display="block";
});

 });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(confirm('Are you sure?')) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "faculte_modifier.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function (html)
        {
            $("#Adresse_" + ID).html(Ad);
            $("#NomDroyen_" + ID).html(NomD);
            $("#NombreEtudiants_" + ID).html(NombEtu);

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [confirm()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm) method like following.

```
if (confirm('Are sure you want to edit')) {
    alert('confirmed');
    // do your stuff here; 
}
```